# 0 gets dropped when posting to Google Forms in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app the records the start time and date using the Calendar.component for each individual calendar component (i.e. let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from:date)) and sends the data to a Google form after another button is pressed. When the Minutes or seconds begins with a 0, the 0 gets dropped and I get a result like this: 4:2:3 for what should be 04:02:03.

Here is the code:

```
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from:date)
        let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from:date)
        let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from:date)

        let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
        let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)


        startTime = "\(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)"
        startDate = "\(month)/\(day)/\(year)"
```

Comment: hour, minutes, seconds, day, month, year are all Integers. Integers don't save prefix 0 as it is useless. Follow my Answer below to get correct result.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need Calendar & Date Object Separately. Date Object will do both.
2. DateFormatter is the correct way of doing this.

> 

```
//        unnecessary code
/*        let calendar = Calendar.current
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from:date)
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from:date)
    let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from:date)
    let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
    let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
    let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
 */

    let date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

    var startTime = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy"
    var startDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```